# composer unable to resolve google/apiclient 1.0.4-beta dependency on packagist

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I'm trying to install:

https://packagist.org/packages/elcodedocle/gplusraffle

which requires:

https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient

by simply doing:

```
   php composer.phar require elcodedocle/gplusraffle 0.1.*@beta
```

and I get this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for elcodedocle/gplusraffle 0.1.*@beta -> satisfiable by elcodedocle/gplusraffle[0.1.0-beta].
    - elcodedocle/gplusraffle 0.1.0-beta requires google/apiclient 1.0.4-beta -> no matching package found.
```

When I do it locally by cloning the repo and installing composer:

```
   git clone https://github.com/elcodedocle/gplusraffle 
   php composer.phar install
```

The dependency is resolved without problem

Why?

(elcodedocle/gplusraffle master matches the 0.1.0-beta tag, so it's the same composer.json, I've checked. And the requirement is also the same: 1.0.4-beta of google/apiclient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by explicitly adding the dependency:

```
php composer.phar require google/apiclient 1.0.4-beta elcodedocle/gplusraffle 0.1.*@beta
```

Although in fact what I wanted was:

```
php composer.phar create-project -s "beta" elcodedocle/gplusraffle
```